# Is there a way to cure poison?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

A few times now, when grinding out levels against Terrors, I've been attacked with Venin Claws, which inflict some sort of poison if the attack connects. If a unit is inflicted, they take 10 damage each turn. I haven't seen this effect wear off yet, so is there a way to remove it? Or am I stuck having to constantly cast healing spells on those units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Poison is cured after 3 turns or with the restore spell that Exemplar class learn, which is a DLC overclass for clerics (Genny, Silque, Tatiana...)

Comment: Which units learn it?

Comment: Exemplar class learn restore, which is a DLC overclass for clerics (Genny, Silque, Tatiana...)